# Error kafka cannot connect zookeeper on Kubernetes(single node)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have problem with run kafka and zookeeper on kubernetes ***single node***, I test with **my laptop and it work** but I run on private server it show error in kafka pod and **I don't know network setting on private server**

I use kompose to convert docker-compose file to k8s yaml file

> zoo1: Temporary failure in name resolution

**How to fix that error?**

Thank you

my deployment and service yaml file

kafka1-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.16.0 (0c01309)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: kafka1
  name: kafka1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: kafka1
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
          value: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:9092
        - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
          value: "1"
        - name: KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS
          value: kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO
        - name: KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR
          value: "1"
        - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
          value: zoo1:2181
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.0.0
        name: kafka1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9092
        resources: {}
      hostname: kafka1
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

kafka1-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.16.0 (0c01309)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: kafka1
  name: kafka1
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "9092"
    port: 9092
    targetPort: 9092
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: kafka1
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

zoo1-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.16.0 (0c01309)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: zoo1
  name: zoo1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: zoo1
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: ZOO_MY_ID
          value: "1"
        - name: ZOO_PORT
          value: "2181"
        - name: ZOO_SERVERS
          value: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888
        image: zookeeper:3.4.9
        name: zoo1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2181
        resources: {}
      hostname: zoo1
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

zoo1-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.16.0 (0c01309)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: zoo1
  name: zoo1
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "2181"
    port: 2181
    targetPort: 2181
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: zoo1
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: thank for reply but I cannot create kafka and zookeeper on helm t always pending and I checked this, a problem is helm cannot create persistent volumes(status is always pending). I am a beginner on k8s it different docker

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem?

Comment: I just want to make kafka connect zookeeper on k8s and I try your way I got a problem about helm(i am not sure I install helm right way) status kafka and  zookeeper pod is always pending

Comment: How about this project? https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator

Comment: for now, it work and I dont know why??

Answer (score 0):

You have to create headless services for kafla and zookeeper

I would recommend to use confluent helm charts to use kafka in kubernetes, you can find how they created headless services.

What are the logs? What's happening exactly?

Hope that's help!

Comment: thank for reply but I cannot create kafka and zookeeper on helm t always pending and I checked this, a problem is helm cannot create persistent volumes(status is always pending). I am a beginner on k8s it different docker

Comment: Concerning the persistent volume, it happen one time, you have to create them yourself.

Comment: Confluent Helm Charts are deprecated